# How can I add specific folders to Places in mintMenu?

Tags: directory, shortcuts

How can I add specific folders to places in mintMenu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Right-click the menu and choose Preferences:
    
   [image: screenshot]
2. Click Places ▸ New:
    
   [image: screenshot]
3. Enter the name and path for the new place, then click OK:
    
   [image: screenshot]
4. The custom place should now be listed in the menu:
    
   [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. In the meantime i had found this solution myself. But you sure will get the Bounty. Nice answer. Note: I have to wait 23 hours to give you the Bounty.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is click add folder from the places menu when you are in the folder that you want to add.

Comment: sorry, i'm not able to comprehend that? Where is the "add folder" option in the places menu?

Comment: He isn't talking about mintMenu, he's talking about the standard menu.

Comment: you edited your question D:!!! now I have to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MintMenu is written in Python. So you should change .py scripts.

It is very easy to change/add items in case of Mint 10.
Right click on Menu button, then select 'Preferences', then select tab 'Places'. From there you will be able to add/remove/change elements of MintMenu Places.

Best wishes,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by editing the `~/.gtk-bookmarks` file. It is a newline separated list of entries found in the bookmarks folder, where each entry follows the format shown below:

```
[URI] [entry-name]
```

It is extremely flexible in that it can handle pretty much any protocol that your system recognizes, including sftp://, smb://, http://, etc.